# Using data-binding in android error: package *.*.databinding does not exist

Tags: android, data-binding

I'm trying to implement data-binding in android app. [This](http://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html) is the link I'm following to set it up. Even after doing all the necessary implements, I'm getting the following error in gradle-build:

> error: package com.example.satpracticeapp.databinding does not exist.

(This package is what I'm importing in my MainActivity.java file)
I tried [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175238) (the data-binding compiler), but it didn't work.

The problem is I've already successfully tried a hello-world app using data-binding and it works. But, when I try to implement it in an app I made a few weeks ago, I get the error I mentioned above. Searching for the solutions, I copy-pasted the gradle files from my successful hello world app to my old app - that too didn't work out.

Here is my app level build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.satpracticeapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
}
```

And here's the buildscript of the project level build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}
```

Here are the links to the minimal version of the three files (if it's needed)

1. [MainActivity.java](http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/4197)
2. [ViewModel.java](http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/4198)
3. [activity_main.xml](http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/4199)

After much hair-pulling, I couldn't figure out the solution and getting the same build error again and again.
So, as a temporary solution, I'm trying to copy-paste my classes and layouts in the working hello world project. What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

After a few hours of pointless searching, I went back to my code. Checked it word by word and found a typing mistake at the name of a binding variable in the xml file. 
Everything works fine now!

Comment: I have had similar problems. It turns out Dagger 2.3 and Gradle 2.0 with databinding library cause some compilation errors. Downgrading dagger to 2.2 seems to help in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, turned out to be a duplicate symbol declaration in one of my *.java classes. It's shown in the Gradle console but it was kinda hidden among the databinding errors. i had about 72 data binding errors and this duplicate symbol error was in the middle so it's easy to miss.