# Using Newer version of Glide Library(4.7.1) causing Binding error issue

Tags: android, binding, crash, imageview, android-glide

When I tried using a newer version of Glide Library gives me Binding Error in all the file. The moment I revert back to the older version, it works.

The version I was using:

```
**api 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.0'**
```

Newer Version I updated:

```
**dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
}**
```

Not sure about the cause of the issue.

**error: package com.xxx.xxx.databinding does not exist**

- it is the same for all class

  org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)

Actual issue I'm facing is this: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49976044/crash-on-using-glide-library/49976172?noredirect=1#comment86975685_49976172`

Comment: no one faced this issue?

Comment: This usually happens when there is an error in annotation processing. Since gradle shows only first 100 errors, data binding eats up the limit. Try adding `gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xmaxerrs" << "1000"
    }
  }` to your app module's build.gradle and build again and look for other errors.

Comment: @glitter Thank you for your comment. Now I can able to get 203 errors which are same. Ex: error: cannot find symbol class ItemSocialfeedBinding for all.

Comment: Even the 203rd error? It's usually the last one for me

Comment: yes all are same error

Comment: anyone? please.

Comment: Will it be possible for you to post the whole build output in a Pastebin or something?

Comment: @gitter check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49976044/crash-on-using-glide-library/49976172?noredirect=1#comment86975685_49976172

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I am able to fix this issue by placing the Glide dependency in both the Gradle files.
Previously, I was trying to add the dependency on one of those files. Surprisingly the older version of the Glide was working not the newer one.
Now I placed the new version of the Glide in the both Gradle files. BOOOOOM! It works.

`My project structure(MVVM):
-core
  - app`

`implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'`